# Enabling Oauth security in swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui

[white label error and config files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1nYE.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuMAj.png)when I tried to enter the authorization token and click on authorize it gives me white label error page someone please help me with this in fixing it.

Comment: We would if there was a unique solution to all authentication problems related to swagger and oauth.

Comment: Please post your Swagger UI OAuth configuration code. A screenshot of the "white label error page" would also be helpful.

Comment: I added the config file and error page please check it out

Comment: Please do not post code as images - images are not searchable and others can't copy/paste code from images. Post your code as text and use the `{}` button to format as code.